# enable EditTextPreference visibility while user check or true the CheckBoxPreference in setting

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences, setting, checkboxpreference, edittextpreference

it is possible set **android:enabled="false"** of **EditTextPreference** this is by default when user check the **[checkboxPreference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FuHQ.png)** if user click then EditTextPreference **enable(true)**..
**if** uncheck then it will go **enable(false)**

[image]

this is the problem..

Comment: I really can't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programetically in your `PreferenceFragment`

```
public class PreferenceFragment extends android.preference.PreferenceFragment
```

use this code: to programetically enable/disable the checkboxes..

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        pref1 = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("bookATrainer");
        pref2 = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("cancelBooking");

        pref1.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (pref1.isChecked()) {
                    pref1.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    pref2.setChecked(true);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
        pref2.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                if (pref2.isChecked()) {
                    pref2.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    pref1.setChecked(true);
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can we do this in MainActivity extands AppCompatActivity??

Comment: in your activity onCreate call the preference fragment using: `android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
 fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new PreferenceFragment()).commit();`...

Comment: [Rafsan Ahmed Bhai](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6139861/rafsanahmad007) this code i have done.. but still i want to enable false.
when user click on setting and true the CheckBoxPreference (cancelBooking) then this EditTextPreference will be true or visible..

Answer (score 0):

Please reword your question but it sounds like you want to enable or disable an option based on a checkbox. Put the dependency under `hourBooking`

```
android:dependency="cancelBooking"
```